# Who is Yakushimaru Ritsuko?

Tags: punchline

At the beginning of episode 3, as *Mikatan* brings a Christmas tree into Ito's room, this conversation happens:

> **Ito:** Wh-What is that?
>
> **Mikatan:** Isn't it obvious? It's Yakushimaru Ritsuko. Oh, I mean, a Christmas tree.

[image]

Who is Yakushimaru Ritsuko supposed to be a reference to? Does the real person has anything to do with the context here?

Comment: [A blogger](http://japaneseinanime.blogspot.com/2015/04/punchline-episode-3.html) suggested it might be a reference to singer Yakushimaru Etsuko. I haven't seen the show so I can't comment on the plausibility of that.

Comment: @Torisuda: It is only a passing reference, though I don't know if it has any connection to the show, or Christmas.

Comment: @Torisuda: By the way, the blog you have there suggests that it is a pun.